# can't use a user control

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-controls

I've just added a user control to a windows phone project, but I can't use it.
what I did after creating the control ( the old fashion way: click add --> UserControl, named it RecordList and added a text block and a button in canvas. Simple), I added the namespace in the MainPage of my project like this: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project1" and in the Content Panel I added the control like this: . But it gives me an error :The type 'local:RecordList' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
I picked this method from this [link](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/why-and-how-to-create-a-user-control-in-windows-phone)

PS: I am a beginner in the software development.

Comment: Try adding the assembly in the namespace. Then use <local:RecordList>, see if that works.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do we add the assembly??

Comment: "xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project1;assembly=%Name of the Assembly%" i.e. (Presentation.Infrastructure) where Presentation is the project name, and Infrastructure is the folder where the control lives.

Comment: Okey it's working now, it seems that the problem is that I didn't build the user control, I didn't know it had to be built. I'm sorry I'm still a beginner

Comment: It's okay. I'll leave it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the assembly in the namespace declaration attribute

**"xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project1;assembly=%Name of the Assembly%"** i.e. (Presentation.Infrastructure) where Presentation is the project name, and Infrastructure is the folder where the control lives. –